# Error building rosjava.jar

Tags: rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to install rosjava from the official instructions: http://code.google.com/p/rosjava/wiki/Welcome

but I'm stuck at the step where I have to build rosjava.jar. When I type `ant dist`, I get this:

```
BUILD FAILED
/opt/ros/javagooglecode/rosjava/build.xml:5: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/opt/ros/javagooglecode/rosjava/build-common.xml:16: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/opt/ros/javagooglecode/rosjava/dependencies.xml:20: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/opt/ros/javagooglecode/rosjava/android/build.xml:6: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/opt/ros/javagooglecode/rosjava/android/library/build.xml:37: Cannot find ${sdk.dir}/tools/ant/pre_setup.xml imported from /opt/ros/javagooglecode/rosjava/android/library/build.xml
```

I followed the solution presented here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159909/ant-cannot-firn-pre-setup-xml-for-an-android-project, but it did not change anything.

Note than when I type android, it is not a recognized command, so I have to type the full path the to Android installation folder on my desktop. I don't know if this could be a problem.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10120/error-building-rosjava.jar/) by [Benoit Larochelle](https://answers.ros.org/users/216/benoit-larochelle/) on ROS Answers with karma: 867 on 2011-05-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to download and configure your Android ADK first.

You need to specify the value of the sdk.dir property for the Java build. One way of doing it is via a -D flag for ant:

```
ant -Dsdk.dir=<path to sdk> dist
```

e.g.

```
ant -Dsdk.dir=/opt/android-sdk-mac_x86 dist
```

Also if you see an error like this:

```
/Users/nah/ros-diamondback/rosjava/android/library/build.xml:77: Unable to resolve target 'android-9'
```

You'll need to set the target property [as appropriate](http://sagistech.blogspot.com/2010/05/android-sdk-error-unable-to-resolve.html). E.g. I had the 2.3.3 SDK installed, so I needed to compile with:

```
ant -Dsdk.dir=/opt/android-sdk-mac_x86 -Dtarget=android-10 dist
```

---

Originally posted by [hawesie](https://answers.ros.org/users/246/hawesie/) with karma: 282 on 2011-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-06-05**:
you don't need to manually pass in these properties if you use the 'android' command to create the local properties file.  Please see the 'android update' command.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to download and configure your Android ADK first, then follow the solution in the stack overflow answer.  The `android` command needs to be setup on your PATH (point to the `tools` directory of your android ADK).  When you are setup correctly, you should be able to type the `android` command.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-06-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1